# how exactly does flutter render widgets?

Tags: flutter, dart, widget, render, customization

I mean an illustration of a customized widget in `flutter` showing how >layouts and >painting are been done during the *rendering* process?

Comment: I'd recommend to watch official video from flutter.dev https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=996ZgFRENMs

Comment: Good and insightful, but an intensive source code explaining these concepts 'll be the best.